# Control parameters for the Jenkins xUnit plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, xunit

I have this `Jenkinsfile` and I use `xUnit` plugin. I want to understand the key words used in this file:

```
node{
  stage ('Checkout')
  {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage ('Build')
  {
    try {
        sh '''
           mvn clean -B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
        '''
      } catch (err) {
        // do nothing
      } finally {
        //step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
       step([$class: 'XUnitBuilder', testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode: 1,
    thresholds: [
        [$class: 'FailedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '1'],
        [$class: 'SkippedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '']],
    tools: [
        [$class: 'JUnitType', deleteOutputFiles: false, failIfNotNew: false, pattern: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml', skipNoTestFiles: true, stopProcessingIfError: false]]
    ])
    }
  }
}
```

What does `SkippedThreshold` mean? 
What is the difference between `failureNewThreshold` and `failureThreshold` and between `unstableNewThreshold` and `unstableThreshold` ?

Thank you for helping me to understand this, I could not find a clear documentation. Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are configuring xUnit the first time, for an existing project, you don't expect each test to be always successful. Some of them might need a bit of tuning, specially when run from a jenkins slave.

As you usually don't want to tag the build as `failed` or `unstable` on known legacy tests, you can specify how much test you would expect to fail/skip.

You have the configuration explained in the doc:
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/jenkins-job-builder/latest/jenkins-job-builder.pdf

> **Parameters**:
>
> *thresholdmode* ( str ) – Whether thresholds represents an absolute number of tests or a percentage. Either ‘number’ or ‘percent’. 
>   (default ‘number’)
>
> *thresholds* ( list ) – Thresholds for both ‘failed’ and ‘skipped’ tests.
>
> - threshold ( dict )  threshold values to set, where missing, xUnit should default to an internal value of 0. Each test threshold should 
>     contain the following:
>
>   - unstable (int)
>   - unstablenew (int)
>   - failure (int)
>   - failurenew (int)

The difference between `failureThreshold` and `unstableThreshold`, is how many tests do you allow to fail before set-up the build as FAILED or UNSTABLE.

The keyword 'new' let you set-up if you authorize the addition of new failing tests, and how many.